# When will JVM trigger major garbage collection?

Tags: java, memory-management, garbage-collection, jvm

I am trying to understand how garbage collection works. I am clear on the following points:

1. JVM will trigger minor GC when it fails to allocate objects to the
   young generation.
2. List item

JVM will trigger full GC(both minor+major GC) when
    the heap is full.

But, how about objects in the young generation and old generation which are no longer in reference, eligible for GC, but there is no GC triggered (i.e. young/old generation heap space is not full, thus no GC occurs)

Does that means those objects will remain in young/old generation heap space until a GC occurs?

My reading materials

- https://plumbr.eu/blog/garbage-collection/minor-gc-vs-major-gc-vs-full-gc
- http://www.cubrid.org/blog/dev-platform/understanding-java-garbage-collection/
- https://www.infoq.com/articles/Java_Garbage_Collection_Distilled

Comment: Which GC algorithm you are referring to? Each algorithm has their own threshold to trigger major GC. https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/vm/gctuning/

Comment: Let's say if it is the default option? Parallel GC?

Comment: This might help: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/vm/gctuning/parallel.html#parallel_collector_ergonomics

Comment: it doesnt explains when and how major GCs occur.

Comment: Previous link gives how allocation happens, if you are looking for when collection triggers, this link might help (only for CMS collector, other collectors might have their own strategies and you can refer their documenatation) https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/vm/gctuning/cms.html#concurrent_mark_sweep_cms_collector

Comment: @Holger can you elaborate further on "Since it is (almost) impossible for these objects to become unreachable without having modified object(s) of the same or even older generation, these objects won’t last too long" this?

Comment: *"Does that means those objects will remain in young/old generation heap space until a GC occurs?"* - does it matter? they are not reachable through references anymore since there is no pointer manipulation possible in java.

Comment: @the8472 it still remains in the old generation and the overall heap usage increases until a full/major GC comes along. The ops team is monitoring the heap usage and they are concerned of the growing heap.

Comment: It makes no sense to be concerned about an application using the heap it was specified to use. However, to ease the pain of the ops team, you may try the “Garbage First” collector (`-XX:+UseG1GC`) and in case, they still think, it’s using too much of what it was told to use, you may experiment with the `-XX:InitiatingHeapOccupancyPercent=…` option.

Comment: @Holger because the ops team is afraid that the full GC does not occur and causes the JVM to go out of memory and the system is dead.

Comment: @Holger which GC algorithm should I choose, if my application uses alot of memory, but they are all short-lived objects. I am using JDK 6. I am aiming for high throughput

Comment: There will always be a full GC before a JVM goes out of memory. Regarding the other question, there’s the [HotSpot Virtual Machine Garbage Collection Tuning Guide](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/vm/gctuning/index.html), but if you are using the EOL Java 6, you’ll have to recheck the availability of each option…

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> it still remains in the old generation and the overall heap usage increases until a full/major GC comes along. The ops team is monitoring the heap usage and they are concerned of the growing heap.

If your goal is monitoring the population of live objects, e.g. to detect leaks, then you should measure heap occupancy immediately after a major GC, not between them.

The information can be extracted from GC log files for example.

> JVM will trigger full GC(both minor+major GC) when the heap is full.

This is not necessarily the case. Decisions when to trigger a collection are based on heuristics that take various goals, such as pause times and throughput into account.

Comment: Yes, the old generation heap space is increasing day by day, yet it doesnt incur a major GC yet.

Comment: can I trigger the major GC to start via WebLogic and take a heap dump before/after the manual major GC? Should I include the live parameter when I dump using jmat? i.e. jmat -dump:live format=b,file=<filename>

Comment: in this case, should I even be of a concern of a growing old generation heap? what I am afraid is a memory leak happening.

Comment: If you're seeing zero major GCs then that does not mean you're having a leak, it means you're allowing the JVM to use a lot more memory than it'll need and it decides to use it to avoid paying the cost of GCs.

Comment: In this case, should I continue to perform a heap dump or to the old generation space algorithm to -XX:+UseParNewGC -XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC alleviate the worries of the operations team that the JVM is going to run out of memory?

Comment: The ops team manually perform GC via WebLogic when they receive alerts of the free space drops to 10% or less, and after a GC, the used heap space returns to 40+%

Comment: You should determine whether you actually have a problem. It seems like you're chasing phantoms.

Comment: I cant determine if I have a memory leak vs huge memory footprint. What are the tell tale signs I should look out for?

Comment: That ought to be a separate question. And there already are many somewhat related question on SO.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, if there is no GC then the objects will exist in the heap.

Actually even after GC object will exist in the heap if it is in the young generation, until it will be overwritten, in case of old it depends on the algorithm - but this is interesting only from security standpoint.

Comment: since most objects are short-lived and live in the young generation heap space, minor GCs will occur frequently, but for old generation heap space, wouldnt it starts to accumulate until it is completely full and it triggers a major/full GC on it's own?